# VBA sql queries are not sending data to Access database

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-word

I was trying to send my datas to Microsoft Access database using VBA Word.I have textbox and ComboBox to enter the data and here is what I have tried so far :

```
Dim name As String
Dim lastname As String
Dim studyPlace As String
Dim faculty As String
Dim marriage As String
Dim address As String
Dim age As String
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

name = UserForm1.ismtxt.Text
lastname = UserForm1.familyatxt.Text
studyPlace = UserForm1.unicombo.Value
faculty = UserForm1.fakultetcombo.Value
marriage = UserForm1.oilacombo.Value
address = UserForm1.adresscombo.Value
age = UserForm1.yoshtxt.Text

Set con = New ADODB.Connection

con.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Pavilion\Documents\IAT.accdb;"
con.Open

sql = "insert into 4IAT (Name,LastName,StudyPlace,Age,Faculty,Marriage,Address) values ('" & name & "','" & lastname & "','" & studyPlace & "','" & age & "','" & faculty & "','" & age & "','" & marriage & "','" & address & "')"


con.Execute sql
con.Close



End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With unicombo
.AddItem "ADU"
.AddItem "Boshqa"
End With

With fakultetcombo
.AddItem "Fizika-Matematika"
.AddItem "Ijtimoiy-iqtisodiyot"
.AddItem "Xorijiy tillar"
.AddItem "Tarix"
.AddItem "Fiologiya"
.AddItem "Tabiiy fanlar"
End With

With oilacombo
.AddItem "Oilali"
.AddItem "boydoq"
End With

With adresscombo
.AddItem "Andijon shahri"
.AddItem "Shahrihon"
.AddItem "Bo'z"
.AddItem "Qo'rg'ontope"
.AddItem "Xo'jaobod"
.AddItem "Andijon Tuman"
End With




End Sub
```

Without combobox I tried to execute with only textbox and it works.But I am not sure whats happening with combobox

Comment: Compare fields count (my result is 7) and values count (accordingly 8 - excess 2nd `age` value). Always check for errors and if then output error message.

Comment: Thanks it works. Post your answer here I will check it  !

Comment: I doubt this is useful to somebody else...

Comment: This code will fail when there is apostrophe in the item. Use escape character or - much better solution - parameters.